# Azure AD disappeared from Azure management portal

Tags: office365, azure, azure-activedirectory

I have an Office 365 account and an Azure subscription. I created an Office 365 AD and connected it to my Azure account.

The directory was listed before and I used it as an auth mechanism for one of the Azure web apps.

The authentication is still working, but I can't see the directory anymore in the azure portal.

When I navigate to it directly using the following URL: https://manage.windowsazure.com/@emmanuelspayze.onmicrosoft.com#Workspaces/ActiveDirectoryExtension/Directory/`tenantid/`directoryQuickStart

I receive a 401 Unauthorized and a blank screen in the portal.

I feel like somehow the directory is still there (since the auth is still working), but it got disconnected from my Azure account.

How I can I link it back to my azure account, given that I cannot access it?

Answer (score 2):

The directories you see listed (and have access to) in the Azure portal are directories that you (as the identity you use to sign in to the Azure portal) are a member of.

What likely happened is that an administrator of the other Azure AD directory (what you're calling the "Office 365 AD") removed that user account.

If you have access to an administrator user account in the "Office 365 AD", then you can probably restore that user (the easiest path is using the Office 365 portal, though you can also use the `Restore-MsolUser` cmdlet from the Azure AD PowerShell module.

So, if the account you normally use to sign in to the Azure portal is `example@outlook.com`, and your "Office 365 AD" is `contoso.com`, and you have access to a user account `admin@contoso.com`: Sign in to the Office 365 admin portal (https://portal.office.com) with `admin@contoso.com`, and restore the deleted user `example@outlook.com`.

If it has been more than 30 days, the user has been hard-deleted, so you will need to do add `example@outlook.com` back into `contoso.com` using the Azure portal. (Again, sign in as `admin@contoso.com`.)